# How to create Flip number View on android

Tags: android

[image]i want to design the following text view using animation. after every counter increased it will display that number.
i m applying the following code but i m getting the exception

code is

```
    package com.agicent.numberflipanimation;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class NumberFlipAnimationActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private FlipSpinnerView flipMeter = null;
        private final int value = 000000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_flip_animation);
            flipMeter = (FlipSpinnerView) findViewById(R.id.Flipmeter);
            final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    try {
                        flipMeter.setValue(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString().trim()), true);
                        text.setText("");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            flipMeter.setValue(value, true);
        }


    }

package com.agicent.numberflipanimation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * @author VinayrajSingh
 * 
 */
class FlipDigit implements AnimationListener {

    private ImageView flipImage_BackUpper = null;
    private ImageView flipImage_BackLower = null;
    private ImageView flipImage_FrontUpper = null;
    private ImageView flipImage_FrontLower = null;

    private Context context;
    private Animation animation1;
    private Animation animation2;
    private int id;
    private OnAnimationComplete onAnimComplete;

    private int animateTo = 0;
    private int animateFrom = 0;

    public interface OnAnimationComplete {
        public void onComplete(int id);
    }

    public FlipDigit(Context act, int id, View view, OnAnimationComplete onAnimComplete) {
        super();
        this.context = act;
        this.id = id;
        this.onAnimComplete = onAnimComplete;

        flipImage_BackUpper = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.FlipMeterSpinner_image_back_upper);
        flipImage_BackLower = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.FlipMeterSpinner_image_back_lower);
        flipImage_FrontUpper = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.FlipMeterSpinner_image_front_upper);
        flipImage_FrontLower = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.FlipMeterSpinner_image_front_lower);

        init();
    }

    public void setDigit(int digit, boolean withAnimation) {

        if (digit < 0)
            digit = 0;
        if (digit > 9)
            digit = 9;

        animateTo = digit;

        if (withAnimation)
            animateDigit(true);
        else
            setDigitImageToAll(digit);
    }

    private void animateDigit(boolean isUpper) {

        animateFrom = getLastDigit(isUpper);
        startAnimation();

    }

    private void init() {

        flipImage_BackUpper.setTag(0);
        flipImage_BackLower.setTag(0);
        flipImage_FrontUpper.setTag(0);
        flipImage_FrontLower.setTag(0);

        animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.flip_point_to_middle);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
        animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.flip_point_from_middle);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(this);

    }

    private void startAnimation() {

        if (animateTo == animateFrom) {
            if (onAnimComplete != null)
                onAnimComplete.onComplete(id);
        } else {
            startDigitAnimation(true);
        }

    }

    private void startDigitAnimation(boolean isUpper) {

        if (isUpper) {
            flipImage_FrontUpper.clearAnimation();
            flipImage_FrontUpper.setAnimation(animation1);
            flipImage_FrontUpper.startAnimation(animation1);

        } else {
            flipImage_FrontLower.clearAnimation();
            flipImage_FrontLower.setAnimation(animation2);
            flipImage_FrontLower.startAnimation(animation2);

        }
    }

    private void incrementFromCode() {
        animateFrom++;
        if (animateFrom < 0)
            animateFrom = 0;

        if (animateFrom > 9)
            animateFrom = 9;

    }

    private int getLastDigit(boolean isUpper) {
        int digit = 0;
        try {
            if (isUpper)
                digit = (Integer) flipImage_FrontUpper.getTag();
            else
                digit = (Integer) flipImage_FrontLower.getTag();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (digit > 9)
            digit = 0;

        return digit;
    }

    private int getDigitToShow() {
        if (animateFrom + 1 > 9)
            return 0;
        else
            return animateFrom + 1;
    }

    private void setDigitImageToAll(int digit) {
        setDigitImage(digit, true, flipImage_BackUpper);
        setDigitImage(digit, false, flipImage_BackLower);
        setDigitImage(digit, true, flipImage_FrontUpper);
        setDigitImage(digit, false, flipImage_FrontLower);

    }

    private void setDigitImage(int digitToShow, boolean isUpper, ImageView image) {
        image.setTag(digitToShow);
        int resource = 0;
        switch (digitToShow) {
        case 0:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_0_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_0_lower;

            break;

        case 1:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_1_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_1_lower;

            break;

        case 2:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_2_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_2_lower;

            break;

        case 3:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_3_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_3_lower;

            break;

        case 4:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_4_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_4_lower;

            break;

        case 5:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_5_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_5_lower;

            break;

        case 6:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_6_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_6_lower;

            break;

        case 7:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_7_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_7_lower;

            break;

        case 8:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_8_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_8_lower;

            break;

        case 9:
            if (isUpper)
                resource = R.drawable.digit_9_upper;
            else
                resource = R.drawable.digit_9_lower;

            break;

        }

        image.setImageResource(resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == animation1) {
            flipImage_FrontUpper.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startDigitAnimation(false);

        } else if (animation == animation2) {

            flipImage_FrontUpper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setDigitImage(getDigitToShow(), true, flipImage_FrontUpper);
            setDigitImage(getDigitToShow(), false, flipImage_BackLower);
            incrementFromCode();
            animateDigit(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        if (animation == animation1) {

            flipImage_FrontLower.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            flipImage_FrontUpper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            setDigitImage(getDigitToShow(), false, flipImage_FrontLower);
            setDigitImage(getDigitToShow(), true, flipImage_BackUpper);

        } else if (animation == animation2) {
            flipImage_FrontLower.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

}


package com.agicent.numberflipanimation;


import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class FlipSpinner extends RelativeLayout {

    private View flipMeterSpinner;
    private Context context;
    private FlipDigit flipDigit = null;
    private int mCurrentDigit;

    public FlipSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }

    public FlipSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }
    public FlipSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }

    private void inflateLayout() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        flipMeterSpinner = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipmeter_spinner, this);

    }

    public View getFlipmeterSpinner() {
        return flipMeterSpinner;
    }

    public void setDigit(int animateTo, boolean withAnimation) {
        flipDigit.setDigit(animateTo, withAnimation);
    }

    /*
     * Initialize all of our class members and variables
     */
    private void initialize() {
        inflateLayout();

        flipDigit = new FlipDigit(context, getId(), flipMeterSpinner, null);

    }

    public int getCurrentDigit() {
        return mCurrentDigit;
    }

}

package com.agicent.numberflipanimation;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FlipSpinnerView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;
    private FlipSpinner[] mDigitSpinners;
    private int NUM_DIGITS = 6;
    private int mCurrentValue;
    private int animationCompleteCounter;
    public FlipSpinnerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }
    public FlipSpinnerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public FlipSpinnerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mDigitSpinners = new FlipSpinner[NUM_DIGITS ];

        // Inflate the view from the layout resource.
        String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(infService);
        li.inflate(R.layout.widget_flipmeter, this, true);

        mDigitSpinners[0] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_1);
        mDigitSpinners[1] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_10);
        mDigitSpinners[2] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_100);
        mDigitSpinners[3] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_1k);
        mDigitSpinners[4] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_10k);
        mDigitSpinners[5] = (FlipSpinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_flipmeter_spinner_100k);

    }

    public void setValue(int value, boolean withAnimation) {

        mCurrentValue = value;
        int tempValue = value;

        for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i) {
            int factor = (int) Math.pow(10, i);

            int digitVal = (int) Math.floor(tempValue / factor);
            tempValue -= (digitVal * factor);
            mDigitSpinners[i].setDigit(digitVal, withAnimation);
            changeAnimationCompleteCounter(withAnimation);
        }

        mDigitSpinners[0].setDigit(tempValue, withAnimation);
        changeAnimationCompleteCounter(withAnimation);

    }

    private synchronized int changeAnimationCompleteCounter(Boolean increment) {
        if (increment == null)
            return animationCompleteCounter;
        else if (increment)
            return ++animationCompleteCounter;
        else
            return --animationCompleteCounter;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mCurrentValue;
    }

    public interface OnValueChangeListener {
        abstract void onValueChange(FlipSpinnerView sender, int newValue);
    }



}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SampleActivity" >

    <com.agicent.numberflipanimation.FlipSpinnerView
        android:id="@+id/Flipmeter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Set Digit" />

</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_back_upper"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:src="@drawable/digit_0_upper" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_back_lower"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_back_upper"
        android:src="@drawable/digit_0_lower" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_front_upper"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:src="@drawable/digit_0_upper" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_front_lower"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FlipMeterSpinner_image_front_upper"
        android:src="@drawable/digit_0_lower" />



</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_100k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_10k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_1k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipmeter_spinner_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and i m getting the following exception

```
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.agicent.numberflipanimation/com.agicent.numberflipanimation.NumberFlipAnimationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.agicent.numberflipanimation.FlipSpinnerView
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.agicent.numberflipanimation.FlipSpinnerView
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:360)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1932)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.agicent.numberflipanimation.NumberFlipAnimationActivity.onCreate(NumberFlipAnimationActivity.java:17)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    ... 11 more
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    ... 25 more
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.agicent.numberflipanimation.FlipSpinnerView.initialize(FlipSpinnerView.java:42)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at com.agicent.numberflipanimation.FlipSpinnerView.<init>(FlipSpinnerView.java:26)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    ... 28 more
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipmeterSpinner" on path: /data/app/com.agicent.numberflipanimation-3.apk
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
10-15 18:43:12.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19161):    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Did you import the library correctly? Have you tried cleaning your code?

Comment: i m not using any lib

Comment: and supported library is already imported

Comment: Shouldn't your XML use `<com.vinayrraj.flipdigit.lib.FlipSpinner` instead?